# Tag synonym [tvOS] and [apple-tvos]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I suggested [apple-tvos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-tvos) as a tag synonym for [tvos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tvos).

Seeing as [apple-tvos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-tvos) currently only has [23 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-tvos), would it be more efficient to just edit and remove the [apple-tvos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-tvos) tag from the questions? A tag with no questions gets deleted(burninated?), right?

Comment: removing the tag from the questions will do. tvos seems to be the term google produces as well.

Answer (score 4):

Somebody has retagged all the [apple-tvos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-tvos) questions; the tag doesn’t exist any more.

Comment: No, the tag exists just fine. Perhaps you are looking in the wrong location? Or did you mean that the `apple-tvos` tag is gone now?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Somebody can't read, I got the tags confused. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: I retagged all the questions after rene's comment.

Comment: Upvoting this answer to prevent [further bumping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf0iN.png)

Comment: Upvoting this answer to prevent further bumping, since that vote has probably been deleted along with its user ^